# MySQL chained AND / OR search

Tags: mysql, sql

this is my table

```
+-------+-------------+
|user_id|permission_id|
+-------+-------------+
|1      |4            |
+-------+-------------+
|1      |5            |
+-------+-------------+
|1      |6            |
+-------+-------------+
|2      |4            |
+-------+-------------+
|2      |5            |
+-------+-------------+
|3      |4            |
+-------+-------------+
|3      |6            |
+-------+-------------+
```

i want a search query where i can search for multiple permissions and get all user_id's that have such permissions.
examples:

```
users with permissions 4 AND 5, will be: user_id 1, 2
users with permissions 4 AND 5 AND 6, will be: user_id 1
users with permissions 4 AND (5 OR 6), will be: user_id 1, 2, 3
```

Thank you in advance!:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use subqueries (and combine them pretty much arbitrarily as you would logical operations) like this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id
FROM permissions
WHERE user_id IN (
    SELECT user_id FROM permissions WHERE permission_id = 4
) AND user_id IN (
    SELECT user_id FROM permissions WHERE permission_id = 5
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select user_id
from userpmissions
group by user_id
```

Then the having clauses are:

```
having sum(permission_id = 4) > 0 and sum(permission_id = 5) > 0
having sum(permission_id = 4) > 0 and sum(permission_id = 5) > 0 and sum(permission_id = 6) > 0
having sum(permission_id = 4) > 0 and sum(permission_id in (5, 6)) > 0
```

I call these types of queries "sets-within-sets" queries, because you are looking for sets of permissions within each user.  I find that `group by` and `having` is the most flexible way of addressing these queries.  I should note that for a particular combination, there might be more efficient methods.

Comment: Thank you, this is great! lets say there would be an aditional column with "createdAt", do you know how to get this value for each permission?

Comment: @jazz . . . This answers the question that you asked.  If you have another question, ask it as *another* question.  Editing this question might invalidate answers, which in turn draws downvotes.